# How to get extra-small navigation bar to display without breaking?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

What do I have to do to my "extra-small" navigation variant below so that it simply displays in a row instead of stacked?

[image]

The larger screens look fine:

[image]

```
        <div class="navbar-collapse visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block">
            <div class="navbar-text">{$company->company_name} - Kundenportal2</div>
            <div class="navbar-text">{ $user->title } { $user->givenname } { $user->surname }</a></div>

            <a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
            </a>

            <a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse visible-xs-block">
            <div class="navbar-text">nn</div>
            <div class="navbar-text">22</div>
            <a class="navbar-text navbar-left" href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
            </a>

            <a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/0cL2qaq1/2/

CSS

```
.navbar-text {
float: left !important;
margin-right: 10px;
}

.navbar-right {
float: right!important;
}
```